# JavaMail Exchange server MimeContent

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I am using JavaMail api and I have to send email through Exchange server and then embed image on the email body. For this I am using ExchangeService for getting connected with Exchange server. Note: If it is SMTP, I would gone through Session and Authenticator.

The challenge I face here is I have to use EmailMessage for sending the mail finally. I dont have option to set the embed message(MIMEContent) in the EmailMessage and send it.

```
try{

                    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
                    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password, domain);
                    service.setCredentials(credentials);
                    service.setUrl(new URI(host));
                    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
                    msg.setSubject(subject); //email subject
                    msg.getFrom().setAddress(from);
                    msg.getToRecipients().add(to); //email receiver
                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart.setContent(bodyStart, "text/html");

                    // creates multi-part
                    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                    MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<123234325>");
                    imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
                    imagePart.attachFile("C:/selenium/ma000xsspf01.png");
                    multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
                    msg.send(); //send email
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Someone please let know how shall i use object "msg" to set the image in it as a embedded one.

Comment: You seem to be mixing together APIs from Exchange Web Services and JavaMail.  There's probably a way to do what you want using just the EWS APIs, but you would need an EWS expert to help you with that.  You might able be able to create the MIME content of the message using the JavaMail APIs and then use the EWS `EmailMessage.setMimeContent` method.

Answer (score 0):

By making use of `Datahandler`.I think this is the one you are looking for [mail with attachment](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-attachment-with-email-using-java-mail-api).

Answer (score 0):

Try along these lines:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(objSession);
MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
String origFileName = null;
origFileName = /* Get File Name here*/;

// set the byte content
DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(/*Get Image Stream or content array*/, "image/jpeg");
imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

// this header connects the html content to the image mime part
imagePart.addHeader("Content-ID", "<" + newContentId + ">");

// set the name of resource - after encoding it with Mime utility
imagePart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(origFileName, "utf-8", null).replaceAll("\r\n", ""));

// set disposition as inline
imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);

MimeMultipart relatedMail = new MimeMultipart("related");
relatedMail.addBodyPart(imagePart);
msg.setContent(relatedMail);
```

Comment: the snippet you shared is good for SMTP connections. In my scenario, I am using Exchange server URL

Comment: That's fine, use the MimeBodyPart code that I shared. How you create the MimeMessage could be your implementation. Doesn't help?